# Carousel UWP Microsoft Toolkit disable swipe

Tags: uwp, carousel, swipe, offset, toolkit

I use Carousel control from Microsoft.UWP.Toolkir.Controls
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/carousel

When we're clicking and holding left mouse button, we can swipe item like in tablet, phohe. It's just like "panoramic" scroll.

So, it's work normaly, but when we're holding and moving pointer (or finger in the tablet) on the first and last item we get white "background" (mb offset) of left (first item), right (last item) sides.

When we're moving and item get some (I don't how to check) horizontal offset -> it come back to previous state.

[start position carousel view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1uEH.png)

[we hold and move first item, left of it we get some offset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hUiM.png)

Can we get and change this offset or disable this option on first and last item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can we get and change this offset or disable this option on first and last item?

[Windows Community Toolkit](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit) is open source, you could check the [Carousel](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/Carousel) source code.

What you said ***'when we're holding and moving pointer (or finger in the tablet) on the first and last item we get white "background" (mb offset) of left (first item), right (last item) sides.'*** just is normal [Manipulation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/input/touch-interactions#manipulation-events) operation. You could see these operations in [CarouselPanel.cs](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/Carousel/CarouselPanel.cs#L94).

To achieve your target, you need to do judgement in `OnManipulationDelta`, if the selecteditem is first or last item, you could terminate Manipulation like the following:

```cs
internal void OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var previousIndex = Carousel.SelectedIndex;
    var delta = Carousel.Orientation == Orientation.Horizontal ? e.Delta.Translation.X : e.Delta.Translation.Y;
    if ((previousIndex == 0 && delta>0)||(previousIndex==Children.Count-1 && delta<0))
    {
        return;
    }
    ........
}
```

The above code just is my simple implementation, if you think it's not good for you, you could change it by yourself.

Then, when you change the source code in Windows Community Toolkit, you would have to compile your custom version for it and add reference to it in your project.

Comment: I solved my main task, created own Panel and changed behavior for last and first. 
I use this panel like:
<Setter.Value>  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <carouselViewPanel:CarouselViewPanel></carouselViewPanel:CarouselViewPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>'  
After that scrolling from first item to 5 item (for example) is disabled. Can you please explain me "what's heppend?". May be I don't correct use ItemsPanel?

Comment: I'm sorry, As I could understand I can't inheritence CarouselPanel and override method?

Comment: @StanislavZinoviev You could inheritence and override its methods, if there're methods for you to override.

Comment: @Bite I've researched source and these methods aren't overidde (They don't have overidde mod) and they're have internal mod so I can't use in my own class if I even inherit CarouselPanel.